Nginx Server: Reverse Proxy displaying 502 bad gateway
The following server with Nginx version 1.22.1:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ip;

    location /getthe/ {
        set $target_url $arg_url;

        if ($target_url = "") {
            return 400 "No target URL specified";
        }
    
        proxy_pass $target_url;
    }
}

When I enter the site into my browser, http://192.168.4.27/getthe/?url=http://example.com, a "502 bad gateway" page comes up.
Also, when I replace proxy_pass with just http://example.com the reverse proxy works fine.
I tried resetting and reinstalling Nginx, but the issue persists. I expect the URL from the URL parameter to be reverse proxied and displayed to the user.

You'll need to define a resolver for this configuration to work (you can read this post to find out why is it required). If you check the nginx error log, you'll see a clear error message "no resolver defined to resolve example.com..."

Ah ok. Thanks!!
